# How to get a row after passing value into the table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named Test

```
Test
Name   Value1(varchar)   Value2(varchar)
A          1                  9
B          10                 19
C          20                 39
D          40                 45
...        ...                ...
```

Now how do I get Name from Test table when I send a value like '8' or '21'etc

Comment: What does "8" or "21" mean in your context, i.e. what is the expected result?

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Passing numbers are string so in my case if I pass 8 then I should get A and if I pass 21 then I should get C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um, why are your columns `VARCHAR`?

```
DECLARE @n INT = 8;

SELECT Name FROM dbo.Test
  WHERE @n BETWEEN CONVERT(INT, Value1) AND CONVERT(INT, Value2);
```

If you have other junk in these columns you may have to do something like this to prevent SQL Server from outsmarting you and trying to convert `'ascfdgt'` to an integer:

```
DECLARE @n INT = 8;

SELECT Name FROM dbo.Test
  WHERE ISNUMERIC(Value1) = 1
    AND ISNUMERIC(Value2) = 1
    AND @n BETWEEN CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Value1) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, Value1) END
               AND CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Value2) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, Value2) END;
```

Now please, either fix the data type of this column, or store these numbers in a different column.

If you pass in `A12` and need to find rows where `Value1` is `A010` and `Value2` is `A029` then it gets a little more complex:

```
DECLARE @n VARCHAR(12) = 'A12';

SELECT Name FROM dbo.Test
  WHERE ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value1, 2, 255)) = 1
    AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value2, 2, 255)) = 1
    AND CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@n, 2, 255)) 
      BETWEEN CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value1, 2, 255)) = 1
        THEN CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Value1, 2, 255)) END
          AND CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value2, 2, 255)) = 1
        THEN CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Value2, 2, 255)) END;
```

See how ugly that is? Can you please, please, please consider fixing this terrible design so you don't have to litter your codebase with spaghetti queries like this?

Comment: Thank you Aaron you are great. Actually columns are primary key and it also use alphanumeric character. Let me ask you one more thing how can I get Name if `value1' has A010 and  `value2` has A029 and pass value like A12

Comment: @Lakhae again I would suggest you fix the schema. If `A` and the number are two separate pieces of data, store the `A` in one column and the numbers in other columns.

Comment: @Lakhae I gave you a workaround but it is really ugly and will perform like crap. You should tell whoever designed this schema that they did not do anyone any favors.